# restore backup database from plesk control panel sql 2014 to my pc sql 2012

Tags: sql-server, backup, host, plesk

I want to restore my backup file that I've gotten from host's sql server (with plesk control panel) to my PC's sql server (version 2012). but I can't restore a higher version backup file to lower version sql server. I can't install sql server V.2014.  (my computer is old. I tried to install it but I couldn't.)
so who can help me?
I need to change my database and again upload it on the host. I need it badly.

Comment: "I can't install sql server V.2014" - sure you can!

Comment: my computer is old. I can't do this. I tried but I couldn't

Comment: get a better computer. We are not here to convince to upgrade your hardware.

Comment: ... or a cloud server. Just a couple of dollars for the time you'll need it.

Comment: oh God! no way to restore my backup file? really?

Comment: I should throw away my laptop. buy a new one and install all software again. I'm afraid that there is no way to restore my backup file in recent days.

Answer (score 0):

If it is required to modify the database somehow, you can do it on your local Plesk server (even in GUI) by means of [database management tools](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/database-servers/database-management-tools.72893/). myLittleAdmin is used for managing MSSQL databases in Plesk for Windows.

So you may want to try to open the database in myLittleAdmin and change it: Domains > example.com > Databases > your database name > click myLittleAdmin.

As for the restoration question: yes, it is not possible as it is limited on MSSQl side that does not allow such a restore.